# perl loop through array of hashes

Tags: perl, loops, syntax

Hi in the debugger I print out the following variable `$x`

```
DB<8> x $x

0  ARRAY(0xdb09e20)

0  HASH(0xe18d450)

  'OBJECT_ID' => 111026746749824

  'TABLE_KEY' => '0-85296-384-X'

  'TABLE_KEY_NAME' => 'VALUE'

1  HASH(0xe18d4e0)

  'OBJECT_ID' => 1000000000108155

  'TABLE_KEY' => '1598-8740'

  'TABLE_KEY_NAME' => 'VALUE'

2  HASH(0xe18d530)

  'OBJECT_ID' => 1000000000108156

  'TABLE_KEY' => '89-7085-418-5'

  'TABLE_KEY_NAME' => 'VALUE'
```

I would like to loop through this and access each `OBJECT ID`

I do not know what syntax to use.

Here is a dump of `$x`

```
[
  {
    OBJECT_ID      => 111026746749824,
    TABLE_KEY      => "0-85296-384-X",
    TABLE_KEY_NAME => "VALUE",
  },
  {
    OBJECT_ID      => 111026746749824,
    TABLE_KEY      => "0537-9987",
    TABLE_KEY_NAME => "VALUE",
  },
  {
    OBJECT_ID      => 1000000000108155,
    TABLE_KEY      => "89-7085-386-3",
    TABLE_KEY_NAME => "VALUE",
  },
  {
    OBJECT_ID      => 1000000000108155,
    TABLE_KEY      => "1598-8740",
    TABLE_KEY_NAME => "VALUE",
  },
  {
    OBJECT_ID      => 1000000000108156,
    TABLE_KEY      => "89-7085-418-5",
    TABLE_KEY_NAME => "VALUE",
  },
  {
    OBJECT_ID      => 1000000000108156,
    TABLE_KEY      => "1598-8651",
    TABLE_KEY_NAME => "VALUE",
  },
  {
    OBJECT_ID      => 1000000000108157,
    TABLE_KEY      => "89-7085-442-8",
    TABLE_KEY_NAME => "VALUE",
  },
  {
    OBJECT_ID      => 1000000000108157,
    TABLE_KEY      => "1598-8597",
    TABLE_KEY_NAME => "VALUE",
  },
]
```

Comment: Did you use the debugger just to look at the value? You can just use [Data::Dumper](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dumper) in your code to get it to give you output at run-time. `use Data::Dumper; print Dumper $x;` Please do that, and then [edit] your question and include the output.

Comment: Please show what you have tried. It's hard to help you to fix your code if we can't see your code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you have an array reference that contains hash references as the elements.

I can tell that it's a an array ref because it's `$x` with a `$` as the sigil, which indicates a reference, and because of the `0  ARRAY(0xdb09e20)`.

So if you `print Dumper` it using [Data::Dumper](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dumper) it, you'll get something like this:

```
[
    {
        'OBJECT_ID'      => 111026746749824,
        'TABLE_KEY'      => '0-85296-384-X',
        'TABLE_KEY_NAME' => 'VALUE',
    },
    {
        'OBJECT_ID'      => 1000000000108155,
        'TABLE_KEY'      => '1598-8740',
        'TABLE_KEY_NAME' => 'VALUE',
    }
]
```

If you look at it in this presentation, it becomes pretty obvious what you need to do.

First, you iterate over the elements in the array reference, which you have to dereference. I'm using a very verbose dereferencing here because I think it's cleaner to read if you don't know exactly what you're doing. You could also do `@$x`.

```
foreach my $elem ( @{ $x } ) {
    # ...
}
```

Now you have `$elem` which contains one of the hash references. To get the `OBJECT_ID` key, you need to access it. Because it's a ref, you need the dereferencing operator `->`.

```
say $elem->{OBJECT_ID};
```

This will print out the `OBJECT_ID` for one element. `say` is like `print` with a newline. You can to load it with `use feature 'say'`.

It comes together like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $x = ...;

foreach my $elem ( @{ $x } ) {
    say $elem->{OBJECT_ID};
}
```

It will print:

```
111026746749824
1000000000108155
```

To learn more about references in Perl, look at [perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html) and [perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html). You can also look at these tutorials on Perlmaven:

- https://perlmaven.com/multi-dimensional-arrays-in-perl
- https://perlmaven.com/multi-dimensional-hashes

Comment: @yankel great :-) next time please include the code you had already tried.

Answer (score 1):

This will do as you ask

```
my @ids = map { $_->{OBJECT_ID} } @$x;

say for @ids;
```

#### output

```
111026746749824
111026746749824
1000000000108155
1000000000108155
1000000000108156
1000000000108156
1000000000108157
1000000000108157
```